# Creating SQL Query for 30,60,90+ Inventory

Tags: sql-server, group-by, datediff, bucket

I need to create a query displaying inventory totals at 30, 60, and 90 day intervals for both the financial and physical date.  I have two tables (inventtrans & inventdim) that contain data joined.  I'd like it to be a single query...

These are my queries:

```
SELECT it.ITEMID, it.DATAAREAID, inventdim.INVENTBATCHID, inventdim.INVENTLOCATIONID, SUM(it.QTY) AS QTY 
    FROM [dbo].[INVENTTRANS] IT
    JOIN Inventdim on inventdim.inventdimid = it.inventdimid and it.DATAAREAID  = inventdim.DATAAREAID
    WHERE DATEDIFF(day,it.DATEPHYSICAL,getdate()) between 0 and 180 OR DATEDIFF(day,it.DATEFINANCIAL,getdate()) between 0 and 180
    GROUP BY  it.ITEMID, it.DATAAREAID, inventdim.INVENTBATCHID, inventdim.INVENTLOCATIONID
GO


SELECT it.ITEMID, it.DATAAREAID, inventdim.INVENTBATCHID, inventdim.INVENTLOCATIONID, SUM(it.QTY) AS QTY
    FROM [dbo].[INVENTTRANS] IT
    JOIN Inventdim on inventdim.inventdimid = it.inventdimid and it.DATAAREAID  = inventdim.DATAAREAID
    GROUP BY  DATEDIFF(day,it.DATEPHYSICAL,getdate()), DATEDIFF(day,it.DATEFINANCIAL,getdate()), it.ITEMID, it.DATAAREAID, inventdim.INVENTBATCHID, inventdim.INVENTLOCATIONID
GO


SELECT distinct it.ITEMID, it.DATAAREAID, inventdim.INVENTBATCHID, inventdim.INVENTLOCATIONID, SUM(it.QTY) AS QTY
    FROM [dbo].[INVENTTRANS] IT
    JOIN Inventdim on inventdim.inventdimid = it.inventdimid and it.DATAAREAID  = inventdim.DATAAREAID
    GROUP BY  it.ITEMID, it.DATAAREAID, inventdim.INVENTBATCHID, inventdim.INVENTLOCATIONID, it.DATEPHYSICAL, it.DATEFINANCIAL
    HAVING DATEDIFF(day,it.DATEPHYSICAL,getdate()) between 0 and 30
        OR DATEDIFF(day,it.DATEPHYSICAL,getdate()) between 31 and 60
        OR DATEDIFF(day,it.DATEPHYSICAL,getdate()) between 61 and 90
        OR DATEDIFF(day,it.DATEPHYSICAL,getdate()) > 90
GO
```

I've been able to get each items total inventory change but I cant get a separate column for each bucket.  My SQL isnt up to speed to get this handled timely and I'm looking for some help.

I need the itemid, dataareaid, inventbatchid, inventlocationid, 30, 60, 90, 90+ columns and I currently just see my QTY column which I assumed has summed those transactions for the item but not with the buckets.

Just different ways I've tried to get what I need, help lol!

Comment: Would you be able to post some sample data?

Comment: Maybe this can help? https://1drv.ms/x/s!Av47yqp5NvPqjWBdEXct6EExqRwF?e=hSKi0d

Answer (score 0):

Pretty vague on details but I think you want something along these lines.

```
SELECT distinct it.ITEMID
    , it.DATAAREAID
    , inventdim.INVENTBATCHID
    , inventdim.INVENTLOCATIONID
    , SUM(it.QTY) AS QTY
    , [0-30] = sum(case when DATEDIFF(day,it.DATEPHYSICAL,getdate()) between 0 and 30 then 1 end)
    , [31-60] = sum(case when DATEDIFF(day,it.DATEPHYSICAL,getdate()) between 31 and 60 then 1 end)
    , [61-90] = sum(case when DATEDIFF(day,it.DATEPHYSICAL,getdate()) between 61 and 90 then 1 end)
    , [>90] = sum(case when DATEDIFF(day,it.DATEPHYSICAL,getdate()) > 90 then 1 end)
FROM [dbo].[INVENTTRANS] IT
JOIN Inventdim on inventdim.inventdimid = it.inventdimid and it.DATAAREAID  = inventdim.DATAAREAID
where it.DATEPHYSICAL > convert(date, getdate())
GROUP BY it.ITEMID
    , it.DATAAREAID
    , inventdim.INVENTBATCHID
    , inventdim.INVENTLOCATIONID
    , it.DATEFINANCIAL
```

Comment: Sean, Thanks for the quick reply!

Sorry I was vague, this is certainly a step closer to what I needed.  I'll try to explain in greater detail:

In each bucket I need an overall count of the inventory.  I was thinking to accomplish this I could sum the total transactions in say the 0-30 range and place that value in the appropriate column.  This as I execute your code makes me realize the QTY column will be useless as the bucket columns would take on that roll.

Comment: SO say I have item "IT001000" I would like to know the I guess "running" totals in each bucket so that I can take current inventory totals and apply the values in a report stretching back the 30,60,90,etc.

Does that make more sense?  This was the result of the above query if it helps:
https://gyazo.com/8a3b7f257bd09e9001c65456fd7fb82f

Also, if I'm going about this the wrong way any pointers would be appreciated!